# Список меток в ревью правки

Tags: дефект, поддержка

Смотрю на [предлагаемую правку](//ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/108017) и вижу метки [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) и [spring](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring).

Однако, обе сравниваемые версии (авторская и версия правки) содержали 3 метки: [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), **[xml](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml)** и [spring](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring). Метка [xml](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml) была удалена [позже](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/567906/revisions) (я использовал вариант <kbd>Улучшить правку</kbd>).

Почему отображается такой набор меток?

Comment: Похоже, что отображаются метки последней ревизии. Можно поэкспериментировать, конечно :) А может, всё дело в том, что было нажато `Править`, а не просто `Принять`.